# Solve the initial value problem $y′=(x+y−2)^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I don't usually have problems with solving ODEs but somehow I can't solve this one. I know that I have to substitute with $u$ and $u'$ but that's it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Hint***

Substitute $z=x+y-2=$ and $z'=y'+1$

Then solve 
$$z'-1=z^2$$
$$\int \frac {dz}{z^2+1}=x+K$$

Comment: Yeah, that's clear now. Thank you very much

Comment: @DjordjeS you're welcom  hope it helped you..